# How to customize vcxproj generation by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, vcxproj

I want to use CMake to generate .vcxproj files. Then I open specific project/solution and work in VS as usual.
How do I customize default configurations, generated by VS generator? In particular, how do I specify in my cmake files (whatever it should be) that I need release runtime for "Debug" configuration? (i.e. /MD instead of /MDd).

As far as I understand, such an option is VS-specific (VS/MSBuild flag) and thus is not manupulated my CMake naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In particular, how do I specify in my cmake files (whatever it should be) that I need release runtime for "Debug" configuration? (i.e. /MD instead of /MDd).

This will work:

```
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreadedDLL"
    CACHE STRING "MSVC runtime library selection")
```

Then all of the targets you build in all configurations will use `-MD`. See the documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

The default value is `MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>DLL` which uses `-MDd` for the `Debug` configuration and `-MD` for all others. This uses [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), which are out of scope for this question.

---

An alternative: you can lean in to CMake's defaults and use the `RelWithDebInfo` build config. If you need to override the optimization flags, you can always set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO`.